# Google Chrome always crashes after opening a page

Tags: google-chrome, crash, gpu

Opening google-chrome and starting any page will lead to "freezing". When start with terminal, it shows some errors:

```
ERROR: gpu_process_host.cc(956)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139

ERROR: gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is

ERROR: command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.

ERROR: chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(228)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.

ERROR: chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(231)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.

ERROR: chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(234)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.

ERROR: chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(238)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.

ERROR: platform_thread_posix.cc(147)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
```

I delete the repeated lines. Actually, this situation arise when I upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, and updated chrome to newest. I have no idea what's the problem about. I searched these output but seems nobody has similar problem.

By the way, vscode sometimes freeze like chrome after that upgrade. I don't know if there are any relationships...

Comment: I have exactly the same issue!

Answer (score 5):

What are you trying to do? Where these errors are getting displayed ? If you are using Selenium and you are getting these errors in the console then add these options into your Selenium code-

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```